# How do I use a custom generator function to feed Keras model.fit samples one by one?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, generator, lstm

### The Problem

Feeding data into Keras LSTM model with my custom generator function (see code below) gives me the following error.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 3177, 2) for input 
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3177, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='masking_9_input'),
name='masking_9_input', description="created by layer 'masking_9_input'"), but it was called on an 
input with incompatible shape (None, None).
```

### Generator function

```
def padded_generator(trajectories=trajectories, max_length=3177):
    X = []
    Y = []
    for trajectory in trajectories.values:
        curr_X = np.hstack([trajectory[0][0]])  
        curr_Y = np.hstack([trajectory[0][2]])
        temp = (np.hstack([trajectory[0][1:]]))
    
        for i, point in enumerate(temp):
            if i >= temp.shape[0] - 1: # Should break at second to last sample. 
                break
            curr_X = np.vstack((curr_X, point)) # Stack next point on existing X
            padded_X = np.squeeze(tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences([curr_X], 
                                                               maxlen= 3177, 
                                                               padding='post',
                                                               dtype=float, 
                                                               value=-10))
            curr_Y = temp[i+1] # Point added to X in next iter. is current target. 
            yield (padded_X, curr_Y)
        
data_gen = padded_generator()
```

A full trajectory here is simply an array of points in the form of

```
[[-0.1843775   0.6867699 ]
 [-1.0841161  -3.0429556 ]
 [ 1.3582058  -0.6040352 ]
 [ 1.8754534  -1.7010269 ]
 ...
 [-2.4015598   0.3573116 ]
 [-1.3986164  -0.95052546]
 [-0.705326   -1.3387672 ]
 [-1.455082   -0.57572746]
 [-3.1130497  -2.7871382 ]]
```

From these, the generator yields a padded partial trajectory X and corresponding label Y each time it is called. These have shape:

```
Shape of X: (3177, 2)
Shape of Y: (2,)
```

### Model

Now, the model i've written for this is quite simple, but it does have the corresponding input shape, and the right masking layer syntax AFAIK.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=-10, input_shape=(3177, 2)))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Then, I run:

```
model.fit(data_gen, verbose=1)
```

And I get the error at the top of the post.

I've googled, but I don't know how to fix this. I am not an expert at all, so I'd appreciate explanations with examples or in simple terms. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think the problem is that by calling your generator (as in data_gen()) it should return a batch of data, but you already called your generator, maybe wrap the code inside an inner function so it works this way?

Comment: You mean wrapping the generator inside a function that yields batches of data instead of single samples? AKA calling the generator multiple times, and then yielding batches instead of single samples?

Comment: A single sample can be a batch if properly formatted, what I am saying is that data_gen must be callable to generate your data, it is not like that right now.

Comment: But the problem persists if i just directly inject 'padded_generator()', if that is what you mean.

Comment: No, again, you generator must be callable, you could also pass padded_generator (note no parenthesis here).

Answer (score 0):

For any future people with the same question:

I'm not really sure what the problem was. My guess is that my generator was feeding the whole tuple (input, label) to the network as an input, while I only desired it to feed the input and not the label. Hence, the error with input_shape. However, the Keras docs state that one should call model.fit(generator_function) with a Python generator function that gives back (inputs, targets), so while it might sound more plausible, I'm not sure if this is the case, or the error messaging is just very unclear.

I fixed it by making a tf.Dataset out of my vanilla generator, simply by running:

```
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        padded_generator,
        output_types= (tf.float32, tf.float32),
        output_shapes= ((3177,2),(1,2))
    )
    data= data.batch(10)
```

The last line ensures batching to create inputs of shape (None, 3177, 2), to feed proper ndims=3 input to the LSTM layers (which gave an error after I fixed the error stated in the question).

Then,

```
   model.fit(data)
```

runs properly.

**Note**: if you have a generator that has function arguments, instead use lambda:

```
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
            lambda: padded_generator(**Function arguments here**),
            output_types= (tf.float32, tf.float32),
            output_shapes= ((3177,2),(1,2))
        )
    data= data.batch(10)
```